# Does enabling alpha blending affect the performance (fillrate) on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, performance

In particular on the 2G and 3G models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Absolutely. (But it's still not as expensive as alpha *testing*.)

[From the OpenGL ES Programming Guide (for the non-3GS PowerVR SGX)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES%5FProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html):

> Another advantage of deferred
>   rendering is that it allows the GPU to
>   perform hidden surface removal before
>   fragments are processed. Pixels that
>   are not visible are discarded without
>   sampling textures or performing
>   fragment processing, significantly
>   reducing the calculations that the GPU
>   must perform to render the scene. To
>   gain the most benefit from this
>   feature, you should try to draw as
>   much of the scene with opaque content
>   as possible and minimize use of
>   blending, alpha testing, and the
>   discard instruction in GLSL shaders.
>   Because the hardware performs hidden
>   surface removal, it is not necessary
>   for your application to sort its
>   geometry from front to back.